# Bash: standard output puzzle

Tags: bash, libreoffice

When one does

```
process > file
```

Standard output gets written to a file only once the process is over. Is there a way to write it right away?

Namely, I'm doing batch conversion odt2pdf with:

```
libreoffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.odt
```

So libreoffice says about which files are processed right away. But when I do:

```
libreoffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.odt > log
```

The information is written only once I close libreoffice. (I want to read the number of lines in the log - and this way I'll kill libreoffice when all files are processed)

**Edit**:

I found a command line option of libreoffice which I misunderstood at first: `--invisible` - so it will kill itself after what it has to do - so I don't need to kill it myself - hence [no problem any more](https://github.com/bk322/bk-goodies/blob/master/bk-odt2pdf.bash).

Comment: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

Comment: try `unbuffer libreoffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.odt > log`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it works! I've found `--invisible` command line option - so I don't need to do that way any more. Thank You so much - I've written down `unbuffer`. This is a very nice tool for tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
unbuffer libreoffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.odt > log
```

Note to general readers, `unbuffer` is not always available as a std binary in old-style Unix platforms and may require a search and installation for a package to support it.

Also note that O.P. @Adobe found that `libreoffice` has an `--invisible` option that solved the issue,  i.e.

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.odt > log
```

I hope this helps.